# How to automatically click submit button - react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react login page with username and password manually inputted,

I want the submit button to automatically click upon page load so it will automatically log in users.

Here is my code.

```
export const LoginForm = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const classes = useStyles();
    const email = 'email@email.com';
    const password = 'mypassword';
    const [authStatus, setStatus] = useState(null);
    const [isSpinnerHidden, setSpinner] = useState(true);
    const { session } = useContext(SessionContext);

    const recaptchaRef = useRef();

    const _onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSpinner(false);

        const authResult = await session.signIn(email, password);
        setSpinner(true);
        console.log(session);
        authResult ? setStatus(authResult) : history.push('/dashboard');

    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={_onSubmit}>
            <Typography
                align='center'
                color='primary'
                variant="h4"
                style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}
            >
                Sign In
            </Typography>
            {authStatus ?
                <Alert
                    severity="error"
                >
                    {authStatus}
                </Alert>
                :
                null
            }
            <TextField
                type='email'
                label="Email"
            />
            <TextField
                type='password'
                label="Password"
            />
            <Link
                onClick={() => history.push('/restore')}
                className={classes.restore}>
                Forgot password?
            </Link>

            
            <MuiButton
                text='Sign In'
                type='submit'
                value='login'
                isSpinnerHidden={isSpinnerHidden}
                className={classes.button}
            />
        </form>

        
    );
};
```

what can I add to this code or change that will make it click on the sign-in button automatically and login the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to automatically click on the submit button, you need to use an `onLoad`

convert your _onSubmit to a windows onload, something like this

```
window.onload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSpinner(false);
    console.log('hello');
    const authResult = await session.signIn(email, password);
    setSpinner(true);
    console.log(session);
    authResult ? setStatus(authResult) : history.push('/dashboard');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think clicking the button automatically is the best experience you can have here.

The better way of doing that here would be to conditionally choose the route based on authentication state *before* you even render the login screen. Something like this:

```
if (isAuthenticated){
  history.push('/dashboard);
} else {
  history.push('/login');
}
```

If for whatever reason you NEED to do it your way, just call your signin function when the components mounts with useEffect

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
export const LoginForm = () => {
    
    ...
  useEffect(() => {
    if(isAuthenticated){ // You'll need to get the auth state from somewhere here
     history.push('/dashboard')
     }
  },[])

    return (
     ...
       
    );
};
```

Comment: I want to automatically sign in using that username and password as soon as I open the login page. That's the goal.

Comment: I plan to implement the check for isAuthenticated, for now, I just want to automatically log in that user.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm just suggesting that waiting for the page to load and THEN send the user to the dashboard is not good. You can do that before by conditionally choosing the route. So when your Index.js loads, for example, it chooses the route before anything else is even loaded